# Remove the reference id from the record when the owner is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Let's say I have a `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

and a `Category` model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :posts
end
```

I can use `dependent: :destroy` to have all the posts deleted when a specific category is deleted, but I don't want to remove the posts, I just want to remove the association to that specific category by just setting the `category_id` column of those posts to `nil`.

Is there a "Rails Way" of doing this out of the box, or do I need to use some callbacks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use dependent: :nullify

Per the Rails guide:

> :nullify causes the foreign key to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not
>   executed.

So you'd have:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :posts,
             dependent: :nullify
end
```

Comment: A more detailed example of how this should be implemented would be useful. As your answer currently stands, somebody inexperienced with Rails might assume that they need to add `dependent: :nullify` as a declaration in their model rather than as part of an options hash passed to an association.